# Android Animations - Moving objects closer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, objectanimator, item-decoration

I have been trying to animate following [scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOMSS.png). Basically I want to start with a number of
[ImageViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) that are arranged vertically and spread out across the screen and after a certain action (button-press etc.) they should move *closer*. It is important to mention that the number of ImageViews **can vary depending on the case (not always 3 like in the picture)** so a generic solution would be preferable.

My first approach was to list the images in a [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview) and *spread* the images with a custom [ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration) as follows:

```
class CustomItemDecorator(private val spaceHeight: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        with(outRect) {
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
                top = spaceHeight
            }
            bottom = spaceHeight
        }
    }
}
```

By removing the ItemDecorator ( `myRecyclerView.removeItemDecoration(my_decorator)` )
I was able to bring the images *closer*.
Although this work fine with any number of images in order to improve the user's experience I would like to **animate** this transition. I have tried to apply some more complex animations to my RecyclerView but nothing has worked until now.

I would be happy for any suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For devices running Android 5+ (API levels 21+), you can use `TransitionManager` to achieve a smooth animation:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot as ViewGroup, Slide())
}
recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
```

Here, *itemDecorator* is the instance of `CustomItemDecorator` which you want to remove and *sceneRoot* is a `ViewGroup` which is a (direct or indirect) parent of all `View`s for which a change of properties (visibility, position, size) should be animated.

Read more about animating `Transition`s:

[Animate layout changes using a transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions)

[Getting Started with Activity & Fragment Transitions](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html)